# Is there a way to create an empty file after a certain pipeline in my python code using apache beam

Tags: python, apache-beam, dataflow

below id my python code where it is running a pipeline.

```
from __future__ import absolute_import
import apache_beam as beam
import argparse
import logging
from apache_beam.options.pipeline_options import PipelineOptions
from apache_beam.io.gcp.internal.clients import bigquery
from datetime import date
today = date.today()
current_date = today.strftime("%Y%m%d")
def run(argv=None):
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    known_args, pipeline_args = parser.parse_known_args(argv)
    p = beam.Pipeline(options=PipelineOptions(pipeline_args))
    (p | 'ReadTable' >> beam.io.Read(beam.io.BigQuerySource(query="SELECT DISTINCT(IF(LENGTH(MOBILE)=10, CONCAT('91',MOBILE),REPLACE(MOBILE,'+91 ','91'))) FROM `whr-asia-datalake-nonprod.WHR_DATALAKE.C4C_CONSUMER_RAW` WHERE REGEXP_CONTAINS(REGEXP_REPLACE(Mobile, ' ', ''),r'^(?:(?:\+|0{0,2})91(\s*[\-]\s*)?|[0]?)?[6789]\d{9}$')",use_standard_sql=True))
       | 'read values' >> beam.Map(lambda x: x.values())
       | 'CSV format' >> beam.Map(lambda row:'|'.join ("WRPOOL|5667788|"+ str(column) +'|"'+"Hi, This msg is from Whirlpool DL" + '"' for column in row))
       | 'Write_to_GCS' >> beam.io.WriteToText('gs://whr-asia-datalake-dev-standard/outbound/Valuefirst/WHR_MOBILE_CNSNT_REQ'+''+ str(current_date),file_name_suffix='.csv',header='SENDER_ID|SHORTCODE|MOBILE_NUM|CONSENT_MSG')
    p.run().wait_until_finish()
if __name__ == '__main__':
    logging.getLogger().setLevel(logging.INFO)
    run()
```

In this code once my csv file is created, I need to also create an empty file. I tried this option after my csv file but it doesn't create an empty file  instead writes csv file names into it.

| 'Create .done File' >> beam.io.WriteToText('gs://whr-asia-datalake-dev-standard/outbound/Valuefirst/Valuefirst'+str(current_date),file_name_suffix='.done'))

So I tried the option as beam.Create('gs://whr-asia-datalake-dev-standard/outbound/Valuefirst/Valuefirst.done')

This is giving an error. Can anyone help with the option to create an empty file.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there are any built-in ways to create empty files.  Your best bet will be to create the empty file in a DoFn after the WriteToText transform using the Cloud Storage API directly